# UITableView: sort events by date in section and time in rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I try to sort my data in an UITableView by date (day month year) in sections and by time (hh:mm:ss) in rows.

I get my data with coredata.
I have read several discussions but it's not clear and not in swift.

```
    lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    return managedObjectContext

    }()

func fetchLog() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Run")
    let sortByTimestamp :NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortByTimestamp]

    do {
        fetchResults = try managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Events]
        resultsArray = fetchResults.reverse()

    } catch let error as NSError {
        // failure
        print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

After that I'm a bit lost when its come to define the number of section and rows in section for UITableView.

Thank you for your help

Jojo

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSFetchedResultsController` and employ a transient property for the date.

Check out the Apple sample code [Date Section Titles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html). It's in Objective-C, but you should try to understand the concept first before you try it in Swift.